# fix unity 360photo in sphere

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, virtual-reality

I want to fix my 360 photo in a sphere. as you see it looks broken when I put photo inside my sphere. Also I want to keep the transparency in my sphere( see the window.)so maybe the shader should include transparency, anyone know how to code it?

[my sphere](https://i.stack.imgur.com/676dE.jpg)

Comment: See nothing wrong :P Kidding aside I think this happens due to differences in the UV mapping between the Unity sphere and whatever was used to create the texture/video. Transparency for video files is a bit tricky to achieve in Unity .. for pictures yes you will need a shader that supports it

Comment: hello ! thanks for reply. So the code should be ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Shader "Custom/Equirectangular" {
Properties {
    _Color ("Main Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
    _MainTex ("Diffuse (RGB) Alpha (A)", 2D) = "gray" {}
}

SubShader{
    Pass {
        Tags {"LightMode" = "Always"}
        Cull Front

        CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag
            #pragma fragmentoption ARB_precision_hint_fastest
            #pragma glsl
            #pragma target 3.0

            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            struct appdata {
               float4 vertex : POSITION;
               float3 normal : NORMAL;
            };

            struct v2f
            {
                float4    pos : SV_POSITION;
                float3    normal : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            v2f vert (appdata v)
            {
                v2f o;
                o.pos = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                o.normal = v.normal;
                return o;
            }

            sampler2D _MainTex;

            #define PI 3.141592653589793

            inline float2 RadialCoords(float3 a_coords)
            {
                float3 a_coords_n = normalize(a_coords);
                float lon = atan2(a_coords_n.z, a_coords_n.x);
                float lat = acos(a_coords_n.y);
                float2 sphereCoords = float2(lon, lat) * (1.0 / PI);
                return float2(1 - (sphereCoords.x * 0.5 + 0.5), 1 - sphereCoords.y);
            }

            float4 frag(v2f IN) : COLOR
            {
                float2 equiUV = RadialCoords(IN.normal);
                return tex2D(_MainTex, equiUV);
            }
        ENDCG
    }
}
FallBack "VertexLit"
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
Shader "Custom/Equirectangular" {
Properties {
    _Color ("Main Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
    _MainTex ("Diffuse (RGB) Alpha (A)", 2D) = "gray" {}
}

SubShader{
    Pass {
        Tags {"LightMode" = "Always" "Queue"="Transparent" "IgnoreProjector"="True" "RenderType"="Transparent"}
        ZWrite Off
        Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha
        Cull Front

        CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag
            #pragma fragmentoption ARB_precision_hint_fastest
            #pragma glsl
            #pragma target 3.0

            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            struct appdata {
               float4 vertex : POSITION;
               float3 normal : NORMAL;
            };

            struct v2f
            {
                float4    pos : SV_POSITION;
                float3    normal : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            v2f vert (appdata v)
            {
                v2f o;
                o.pos = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                o.normal = v.normal;
                return o;
            }

            sampler2D _MainTex;

            #define PI 3.141592653589793

            inline float2 RadialCoords(float3 a_coords)
            {
                float3 a_coords_n = normalize(a_coords);
                float lon = atan2(a_coords_n.z, a_coords_n.x);
                float lat = acos(a_coords_n.y);
                float2 sphereCoords = float2(lon, lat) * (1.0 / PI);
                return float2(1 - (sphereCoords.x * 0.5 + 0.5), 1 - sphereCoords.y);
            }

            float4 frag(v2f IN) : COLOR
            {
                float2 equiUV = RadialCoords(IN.normal);
                return tex2D(_MainTex, equiUV);
            }
        ENDCG
    }
}
FallBack "VertexLit"
```

}